# NInject and Quartz.net problems

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have been reading a lot for DI and Quartz.net using ninject and I can't make it run. I'm trying to follow [this](http://codein60seconds.blogspot.com.es/2015/08/quartz-with-ninject-dependency-injection.html) link. This is my code:

This is the job:

```
    public class ClientsImportJob : IJob
{
    private readonly IUserClientImportService _userClientImportService;

    public ClientsImportJob(IUserClientImportService userClientImportService)
    {
        _userClientImportService = userClientImportService;
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        _userClientImportService.ProcessFiles();

    }       
}
```

This is the Factory:

```
    public class NInjectJobFactory : SimpleJobFactory
{
    readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public NInjectJobFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this._kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        try
        {
            return (IJob) this._kernel.Get(bundle.JobDetail.JobType); // will inject dependencies that the job requires
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new SchedulerException(string.Format("Problem while instantiating job '{0}' from the NinjectJobFactory.", bundle.JobDetail.Key), e);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is where I call the scheduller:

```
    public class QuartzService
{

    public static void ScheduleImportTask()
    {
        var kernel = InitializeNinjectKernel();
        var scheduler = kernel.Get<IScheduler>();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(
            JobBuilder.Create<ClientsImportJob>().Build(),
            TriggerBuilder.Create().WithSimpleSchedule(s => s.WithIntervalInSeconds(10).RepeatForever()).Build());
        scheduler.Start();

    }

    private static IKernel InitializeNinjectKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind<IScheduler>().ToMethod(x =>
        {
            var sched = new StdSchedulerFactory().GetScheduler();
            sched.JobFactory = new NInjectJobFactory(kernel);
            return sched;
        });

        kernel.Bind<IUserClientImportService>().To<UserClientImportService>();

        return kernel;
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: Execute method is not reached in my job. But if I delete the constructor everything works fine

Comment: But, the  ````UserClientImportService```` has dependencies? if it has try to bind it on the ````InitializeNinjectKernel````.

Comment: What happens if you add a breakpoint in the factory? Can you create an instance of your job class by calling ninject directly?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is working now. Setting a breakpoint in the Factory I realized that I needed to bind more dependencies. Everything is fine now.